# BroadcastReceiver and ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED working partialy in Android 9.0

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

I am trying to catch the event from the pairing process with the android via Broadcast receiver. As it seems, the `BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDING` is works, but the `BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED` not.

In the old android versions this worked (tried with Android 6 and 7), however with the newer ones (tried Android 9, several devices) this does not work. In order to reproduce the problem I've made a simple program:

Java file:

```java
package com.example.bluetoothtest;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    BroadcastReceiver receiver;
    BluetoothDevice mDevice;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String action = intent.getAction();
                if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED.equals(action)){
                    mDevice = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                    if (mDevice.getBondState() == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
                        //means device paired
                        Log.d("bt", "bonded");
                    }
                    else if(mDevice.getBondState() == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDING) {
                        Log.d("bt", "bonding");
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED);
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.bluetoothtest">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />

</manifest>
```

Did anybody else notice this problem? Am I missing a permission? Couldn't find anything relevant on the net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced a similar problem. I have noticed one thing with devices such as HeadPhone, mouse or keyboard is that when you pair such devices, it is immediately connected to our Android device.
So android send us

> android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_CONNECTED

connected broadcast immediately. In case we receive this broadcast, it is safe to assume that Bluetooth device is already paired.

I would recommend adding this permission for Android 12 and above devices to listen to the connected broadcast.

> android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT

Answer (score 3):

You should try to retrieve the `EXTRA_BOND_STATE` like that :

```
val state = intent.extras?.get(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_BOND_STATE) as Int
```

Comment: @ZZZ Please share an example of your code. What is not triggered ? The `onReceive()` callback ?

Comment: @StevenTV, now I know why is not triggered anymore, through https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions, and I guess your working solution was targeting lower version of Android. EXTRA_BOND_STATE is not in the exceptions list.