# Android is not broadcasting ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED when the device gets bonded

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt

I have a broadcast receiver for BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED that looks something like this:

```
fun Int.toBondStateDescription() = when (this) {
    BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED -> "BONDED"
    BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDING -> "BONDING"
    BluetoothDevice.BOND_NONE -> "NOT BONDED"
    else -> "ERROR: $this"
}

when (intent?.action) {
     BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED -> {
          val device = intent.getParcelableExtra<BluetoothDevice>(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE)
          val previousBondState = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_PREVIOUS_BOND_STATE, -1)
          val bondState = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_BOND_STATE, -1)
          val bondTransition = "${previousBondState.toBondStateDescription()} to " + bondState.toBondStateDescription()
          Log.w("Bond state change", "${device?.address} bond state changed | $bondTransition")
     }
}
```

This works great when the state goes from `BOND_NONE` to `BOND_BONDING`, or the other way around. However, Im not getting anything when it goes from `BOND_BONDING` to `BOND_BONDED`. If I manually get the bond state of the device, I can see that it is bonded, but I'm never notified about it.

Am I missing something?

Example log:

```
// Connection begins
D/BluetoothGatt: connect() - device: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, auto: false
D/BluetoothGatt: registerApp()
D/BluetoothGatt: registerApp() - UUID=1b5f1492-f53f-4d06-8704-6de7b0222769
D/BluetoothGatt: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=9
D/BluetoothGatt: onClientConnectionState() - status=0 clientIf=9 device=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
D/BluetoothGatt: onConnectionUpdated() - Device=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX interval=36 latency=0 timeout=500 status=42
D/MyBroadcastReceiver: ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED
D/Bond state change: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX bond state changed | NOT BONDED to BONDING

// Android stuff
V/FA: Connecting to remote service
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
V/FA: Activity paused, time: 1735662355
D/FA: Connected to remote service
V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 2
V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 1735663677

// Then I press a button that prints out the bond state, I can see that it is bonded but I was never notified
D/BOND STATE: BONDED
```

Comment: your code looks fine…can you share a log so we can see the sequence of events?

Comment: @MartijnvanWelie I edited the question. I've seen a couple other questions about the same issue without a solution, seems to be an Android quirk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be an issue on the side of Android. I had already found some similar questions but they also remain unsolved, see here:

- [Bluetooth BLE device not getting Bonded after pairing process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69736676/bluetooth-ble-device-not-getting-bonded-after-pairing-process)
- [BroadcastReceiver and ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED working partialy in Android 9.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57141976/broadcastreceiver-and-action-bond-state-changed-working-partialy-in-android-9-0)

I've created an issue for Google to take a look at. You can find it [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/236035219).

I will update this answer if anything new comes out.